# Android Activity Group - second activity always shows first activity menu

Tags: android

I have one problem using ActivityGroup. I have two activities inside an ActivityGroup and both of them use a menu (overriding the onCreateOptionMenu and onOptionsItemSelected).

Both activity have different menus.

Well, the problem is that the second activity always show the first activity menu,

Any idea about this issue?

Below is my code

```
public class myActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup {

----

    public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {
        Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id, intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
        if (window != null) {
            mIdList.add(Id);
            View view = window.getDecorView();
            history.add(view);
            setContentView(view);
        }
    }

        public void back() {
        if (history.size() > 0) {
            int lastActivityIndex = history.size() - 1;
            int lastIDIndex = mIdList.size() - 1;

            String activityId = mIdList.get(lastIDIndex);
            Log.d(TAG, "activityId:" + activityId);

            history.remove(lastActivityIndex);
            mIdList.remove(lastIDIndex);
            setContentView(history.get(history.size() - 1));
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getCurrentActivity();   
        return current.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        Activity current = manager.getCurrentActivity();
        return current.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager();
        Activity current = manager.getCurrentActivity();
        return current.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



public class ChildActivity1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //add menu here
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.settings_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
      public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //handle on menu item selected here
        return true;
    }
}



public class ChildActivity2 extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        //add menu here
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.offer_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        //handle on menu item selected here
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I have look at that post and i cannot find any different with my code above, can you please help me.i'm kind a stuck now.

Comment: double check that `offer_menu.xml` and `settings_menu.xml` are not same.

Comment: offer_menu.xml have one menu item, settings_menu.xml menu have two menu items. both are not same ;(

Comment: I've logged on each child activity, seems like second activity "onCreateOptionsMenu"  not get called, any idea why this happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add the activities, the "current" activity is that last one added.  I suspect that if you interact with the other activity then activate the options menu it will work.

Try retrieving the activity you need using the String Id:

```
LocalActivityManager manager = getLocalActivityManager(); 
Activity a = manager.getActivity(id); 
return a.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

Comment: tried this option as well,seems like it's not calling the second activity "onCreateOptionsMenu" method. any idea on this

Comment: Check the name of the activity being returned by the LocalActivityManager.  Are you ever seeing the name of the desired activity?

Comment: yes, I've add logged message to log the current activity name and  it's print desired activity name. 
I can see it's do call the correct "onPrepareOptionsMenu" method in my child activity. 
what i seen is when my second activity created it's getting call "onPrepareOptionsMenu"  not the "onCreateOptionsMenu" method. that's why i'm getting the first activity menu in second activity also.

My qustion is now, when a child activity in a activity group create a menu,does that mean other child activity's
"onCreateOptionsMenu" method not get called ???.